# Consulta Nombre y Contenido Columna

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

Necesito crear la siguiente consulta SQL.

> Selecciona todas las Tablas que tengan una Columna llamada **'x'** y que
>   el contenido de dicha columna NO se encuentre en la columna **'y'** de la
>   tabla usuarios.

Tengo la primera parte...

Selecciona todas las Tablas que tengan una Columna llamada **'x'**, podemos eliminar si queremos el nombre de la tabla y la clausula `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT      COLUMN_NAME AS 'ColumnName',
            TABLE_NAME AS  'TableName'

FROM        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

WHERE       COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%NOMBRE_COLUMNA_X%'

ORDER BY    TableName,
            ColumnName;
```

Pero quiero anadir, supongo que con un subselect, que solo me devuelva las columnas cuyo valor NO se encuentre en algunas de las filas de la tabla USUARIOS.

**EX.** Necesitamos crear claves foraneas en todas las tablas de la BD que contengan una columna que referencie a la PK de la tabla `USUARIOS` (Sabemos el nombre de dicha columna). Gracias a esta sentencia de arriba y sabiendo que todas las columnas que han de ser `FK` se llaman igual podemos saber todas las tablas de la BD que necesitan ser `FK` de la tabla usuarios.

Pero... resulta que hay datos (en la columna que va a ser FK) en dichas tablas que no se encuentran en la tabla Usuarios... asi que necesitamos saber eso para no obtener...

```
ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Ya que si intentamos hacer FK a la PK de la tabla Usuarios, una tabla que contiene datos que no se encuentran en Usuarios... obtenemos dicho error.

Tengo tambien la segunda consulta necesaria que selecciona todas las filas de una tabla concreta que no tengan resultados en la tabla usuarios...

```
SELECT  COLUMNA_NAME_X

FROM    TABLE_NAME

WHERE   COLUMNA_NAME_X NOT IN(
  SELECT PK
  FROM users
)
```

No se pueden mezclar dichas consultas, pero se me ocurre algo como... crear una vista o un alias de todos los resultados de la primera consulta y usarlo en el `FROM` de la segunda...

Comment: Que has probado? No parece que hayas probado de hacer la 2a parte del ejercicio. Por otra parte, aquí no hacemos deberes, resolvemos problemas y dudas que tienen los usuarios con las cosas que ellos mismos hayan probado. Si no es el caso, te recomiendo que edites la pregunta y aclares estos puntos.

Comment: Logicamente he probado antes y no se me ocurre, si no no perderia el tiempo escribiendo y detallando mi consulta... He probado a anadir clausulas al WHERE --- AND NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT login
              FROM users
              WHERE login NOT IN (
                SELECT...
              )
            )

Comment: Añade las pruebas que hayas hecho o como tenias pensado hacerlo en la pregunta para dejar eso claro.